# Do we need both [file-server] and [file-sharing] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question is a follow-up to [Burninate [server]](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/burninate-server), which proposes to burninate [server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) because it's not used for questions about the piece of hardware.

Now, the description of [file-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-server) is

> A file server is a computer attached to a network that has the primary purpose of providing a location for shared disk access[...]

It seems to have the same problem. Furthermore, if you look at the [questions tagged with it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-server), it looks pretty redundant with either [sshfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sshfs), [nfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs), [samba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samba), or whichever the real daemon used for sharing files is. Ah, and there is also a [file-sharing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing) tag.

Do we need both [file-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-server) and [file-sharing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing)? [file-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-server) is useless if one of [samba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samba), [nfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs), etc. is also used and [file-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-server) and [file-sharing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing) seem pretty redundant. There are only two questions tagged [file-sharing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing).

Answer (score 2):

I've edited the tag wiki for [file-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-server) to clarify that it's about file server programs.

The tag [file-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-server) conveys that the question is about the server end. A lot of questions are misusing it by any reasonable definition, though, so I'm uncertain whether it's worth keeping.

[file-sharing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing) is ambiguous: it's use both for LAN situations (where it's similar to [file-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-server)) and for WAN situations (e.g. file sharing over peer-to-peer networks). I'm not sure what to do about that.